# find the attribute value of xml from the cell content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a table of 100 columns. For each mouse hover on the cells i want to call a single function.

```
$('.cellNumber1').hover(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
    url: "js/images/excel2XML.xml" ,
    dataType: "xml" ,
    success: function(xml) { 
        $title=$(xml).find('property').attr('name');
        $('.context-menu-one11').attr('title',$title);
            jQuery('.cellNumber1').jBox('Tooltip', {    });
            incr++;
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Similarly cellNumber2 to cellNumber100 i want to call the same function. But have to change the class name from the function called inside the hover function.

*What i want is to replace the classname wherever it comes in the function for each cells*.
In the straight forward way and as a beginner, what i find is writing 100 functions with replacing the class name and i find it as too much

### part-2

I have the cell content as numbers from 1 to 100. similarly i have the xml with one of the attributes named **rowpos** with the matching values ie from 1 to 100.
When cell 2 is hovered i want to retrieve the xml attribute **rowpos** having value 2 and get the values

XML

```
<parent>
    <property rowpos="2" data="Cell Value2">
         <values id='02'/>
    <property rowpos="3" data="Cell Value3">
         <values id='04'/>
      .................
```

Comment: Why not use a common class name, define the handler; and use `this` to track reference inside ajax success.

Comment: You can even use a loop. `for (var i = 1; i<=100;i++ ){jQuery('.cellNumber' + i).jBox('Tooltip', {    });}`

Comment: In that case the only way to identify the cell is retrieving the content of the cell and then compairing it with the xml attribute

Comment: @Rajesh : thanks and what about the hover function

Answer (score 0):

Use a common class just use the `this` variable to retrieve only the individual cell

```
$('.cell').hover(function(){
   var cell= this;
  $.ajax({
type: "GET" ,
url: "js/images/excel2XML.xml" ,
dataType: "xml" ,
success: function(xml) { 
    $title=$(xml).find('property').attr('name');
    $('.context-menu-one11').attr('title',$title);
        jQuery(cell).jBox('Tooltip', {    });
        incr++;
    }
}
});
});
```

As for part 2 or your question if your xml is in the same order as your rows (meaning the first property is row1 the second property is row 2 so on and so forth) you wouldn't even need to use the row property. You could access it using its index like this

```
var index=$('.cell').index(cell);
var xmlcell=$(xml).children('property')[index];
var xmlprop=$(xmlcell).attr('data'); // or anything else you want to do with the cell
```

Comment: in this scenario, can u check the part2 @Binvention

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented, you can create a loop, but instead of using it for tooltip, you can have a loop  for creating `hover` event and you can use `this` to point to current object/cell. Also binding these events inside a function `registerEvents()` in my case, makes it easy for debugging, since all events are encapsulated in it.

```
function registerEvents() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

    $('.cellNumber' + i).hover(function() {
        // Hold current context and use it to success handler
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "js/images/excel2XML.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
              $title = $(xml).find('property').attr('name');
              $('.context-menu-one11').attr('title', $title);
              jQuery(self).jBox('Tooltip', {});
              incr++;
            }
          }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: how shall i call the registerEvents() @Rajesh

Comment: You can call it on load or when you want to register events. Idea is to encapsulate all events in a function to make debug easier. But you can even copy loop inside and paste it where you were trying to bind events

Comment: ok. if iam giving same class name foe all cells then how to to get the content of that cell.  if one cell is made like this ; `<span  title="My tip"  class="theSameclassName">676</span>`   how to get content 676

Comment: I'm assuming `span` is inside `cell`, you can do this: `$(self).find('.theSameclassName').innerHTML()`

Comment: but no. it is the whole cell.   before it was the `<span title="My tip" class="context-menu-one676">676</span>`

Comment: @tonyStark, `.cellNumber1` would represent cell and inside this cell, you have span with `theSameclassName`. right? If yes, then above code in comment would work. Also, check `textContent` property. I would recommend it over `innerHTML`